# Difference between “Forget it” and “No way”

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Could you please tell me the best answer to the following question and the difference between “Forget it” and “No way”?

- Mum, can I stay inside and watch cartoons?
- __________. I need you to help me in the garden.

A. Never mind

B. No way

C. No problem

D. Forget it

Answer (score 1):

> Mum, can I stay inside and watch cartoons?
>
> __________. I need you to help me in the garden.

In the above blank, the most suitable phrase would be **No way**. That would indicate the mother's reluctance on her child watching cartoons, instead of helping her with her chores.

**no way** - *under no circumstances; no or not in any way; used to tell someone that something is impossible* [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-way)

> "Can I go with you guys?" "No way – this is just for big kids."

**forget it** - *used to tell someone that what they want is impossible* [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forget-it)

> "I'd like to take next week off." "Forget it, we're way too busy."

Now, according to the meaning and the examples, both the terms are very similar to each other. In many cases, they can be used interchangeably as well.

Comment: Is one of them stronger in tone?

Comment: @user10871523 I would say "No way" is more stronger. It almost sounds like an imperative sentence more than an assertive one. "Forget it" would more vividly involve a somewhat softer and childish tone, with a hint of amusement in it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.